# I cannot add python interpreter for PyDev in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

Every time it gets stuck on "operation in progress..." after I click on 'new' or 'quick autoconfig' or 'manual autoconfig'.

This is a link to screenshot where it gets stuck:

[image: This is a link to screenshot where it gets stuck.]

Comment: I used to use `PyDev` too in very beginning of my Python programming. Later on I found, that working in plain text editor (e.g. vim) and on command line is much more direct and productive as there is no IDE doing some magic procedures which I do not understand. If you check Python videos on YouTube, you will notice, that most of presenters use similar setup. The simpler environment, the better. Sorry for not providing answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what that does is running:

`python eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_XXXX/pysrc/interpreterInfo.py`

And parsing the output from that code... for some reason it seems to be getting stuck in your machine.

Try running that manually (updating to point to your installation) to see what happens in that case.

Comment: Hi, I am a beginner. Can you please tell me how to do it manually? I didn't get it.

Comment: This is to check why it didn't work: execute (in a Terminal from Ubuntu) the command I posted (`python ...interpreterInfo.py`, fixing the path for your installation) and see if it works or not and the output.

Comment: It gave the following output-
(some xml file)
File "/home/shubham/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.5.5.201603221110/pysrc//interpreterInfo.py", line 264, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Ok, this is so that it shows the output (ugly hack for some platforms, so that it releases the output).')
RuntimeError: Ok, this is so that it shows the output (ugly hack for some platforms, so that it releases the output).

Comment: Humm, that seems to be Ok... if instead of the automatic, config, you select the 'manual' option and specify the interpreter directly, does it work?

Comment: I was thinking about possible causes here... do you think it's possible that you have a symbolic link cycle (the analyzer may be recursing when trying to analyze the files in your PYTHONPATH)?...Another possilbe reason could be if you have a FIFO file in your path (see: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/681 as a reference).